# Odoo cannot import Python module

Tags: python, module, odoo

I have created the custom module in Odoo12. The module has a the function with @api.model to send the data to another local server.

I cannot `import pydantic` to the code or any other modules from python. I cannot even import numpy

I have tried to install the library in virtual reality, using the installed python on the computer, and add pydantic to the requirements.txt file.

Comment: have you added the package folder to your python PATH?

Comment: Have you tried executing `pip install pydantic`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.